# Getting error BC30456 in the generated Global.asax file when debugging the application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to get an old ASP.NET web app to run. It wasn't a complete project, I had to piece it together from bits and pieces I found throughout our network, since the original developer didn't put it into source control. I think he might have started it using .NET 2 but am not sure. It's old enough he might have used .NET 1.1. Anyway, I've upgraded it to .NET 4.5.2, which is what most of our apps are written at and is the only version supported on our IIS servers.

I can build on my machine the app fine. However, when I debug it, it crashes in the Global_asax file. I've been struggling with this for weeks. When I upgraded it, I made it a Visual Studio Web Application. I'm guessing it was originally created as something called a VS Web Site. I don't know, because like I said, the guy didn't leave a complete version of it anywhere. Here's what the code in the Global.asax.vb looked like, before I got error BC30456:

```vb
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits HttpApplication

    Public Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        'Dim emptyRouteCollection As New RouteCollection()   'this app was never written with routing in mind
        'RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(emptyRouteCollection)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've been struggling with another error, so I thought commenting out the two executable lines in Application_Start would help. Here's what it looks like now:

```vb
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits HttpApplication

    Public Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started
        'RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        'Dim emptyRouteCollection As New RouteCollection()   'this app was never written with routing in mind
        'RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(emptyRouteCollection)
        'BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    End Sub
End Class
```

That removed the other error I was getting, but now I get error bc30456. Here's what the error looks like now:

> Compilation Error
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'Context' is not a member of 'Timetrack.Global_asax'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 43:         Protected ReadOnly Property Profile() As System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile
> Line 44:             Get
> Line 45:                 Return > CType(Me.Context.Profile,System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile)
> Line 46:             End Get
> Line 47:         End Property

This comes from the temporary generated file in this location:

> C:\Users\rod\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\0d381487\e4925ef1\App_global.asax.z_dugpyo.0.vb

I've looked up error BC30456. I know that the likely cause is due to a private variable not visible to calling code, but since this is Visual Studio generated code, I don't know where this `Context` might be, that it can't find.

Furthermore, I clicked on the browser's link to "Show Detailed Compiler Output", which showed me this:

> Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 14.8.3752
> for Visual Basic 2012
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to Visual Basic 2012, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the Visual Basic programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533241
>
> C:\Users\rod\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\0d381487\e4925ef1\App_global.asax.z_dugpyo.0.vb(45) : error BC30456: 'Context' is not a member of 'Timetrack.Global_asax'.

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I looked up the error message about VB Compile for VS 2012 not being the latest version. This led me to this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36020. That suggests to me that it's related to .NET 4.5.2. However, that's the version of .NET we're using on our IIS server. I can't upgrade it.

Comment: You may consider creating a new project in VS 2019 (Visual Basic | All Platforms | Web => ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) => MVC ) - based on the code from the "Global.asax" file that you posted. Build the new project and run it to make sure it works. After you've confirmed that the default project runs, add the relevant code to the new project - periodically testing that it still builds/runs. You've not added any information about the project including what it does and how many pages it contains, etc...-it may be in your interest to not use any of the old code.

Comment: Good questions, @user9938. The current project has 11 pages in it. It is comprised of 12 projects. There are 9 original projects, I added 3-unit test projects. The original coder used lots of convoluted coding. For example, some of those 9 projects have methods of a class whose sole purpose is to call another method of another class in a diffferent project. I like your idea, but I must get permissions, first. I've purposed before to re-write the app. Each time I've asked I've been ordered not to.